# Unable to export Gltf model animations from Marmoset toolbag

Tags: three.js, fbx, gltf

I was trying to export an object from marmoset toolbag which is textured and animated. However, even though i could play animation in marmoset, im unable to find the same when I export it as gltf file from marmoset. It is unable to export with animations.

I would use the same gltf/glb file in three.js import, but unable play the animation.

[GLB file export from marmoset toolbag: Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vgiix3UnfaiYS1vi5y7_R7fosOswFGvC/view?usp=sharing)

[FBX FILE: Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o3rRIyru-pPTzHbh1_iX1A43OYDY48R8/view?usp=sharing)

```
var animations =  gltf.animations;
 if ( animations && animations.length ) {

                          mixerf = new THREE.AnimationMixer( Objloaded1 );

                             for ( var i = 0; i < animations.length; i ++ ) {

                                   mixerf.clipAction(  animations[ i ] ).play();

                                  }

                         }
```

with this above code i'm able to play animations of other gltf models but not the one from marmoset. kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Now,

I have tried contacting marmoset support. They confirm that there is no animation support for .gltf export yet.

Answer (score 1):

Upon inspection, it is clear the .glb file you provide contains no animation information. Perhaps Marmoset Toolbag's glTF exporter doesn't support animations yet, or perhaps there's an export option you didn't check? I don't own that software, so I can't help you with that part.

I downloaded the FBX file you provided and ran it through the FBX2glTF tool. This does result in [a .glb file with a functional animation](https://gltf.insimo.com/vzd-Fzk615bFMxK4M_qaXjX0VuK24qz39snfgQw.ckbWb8SEOrIKmCzXCamRSHPCsKBiGlhmPm8bbw).